# Add custom category using categories json file is not working . I am using allure 2.6 command line tool

Tags: selenium-webdriver, allure

I created a categories json file with the following format:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Iored tests", 
    "matchedStatuses": ["skipped"] 
  },
  {
    "name": "Inructure problems",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken", "failed"]
    "messageRegex": ".*bye-bye.*", 
  },
  {
    "name": "Outed tests",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken"]
    "traceRegex": ".*FileNotFoundException.*", 
  },
  {
    "name": "Prot defects",
    "matchedStatuses": ["failed"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Tst defects",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken"]
  }
]
```

and added this file to the allure-results folder and generate the report using allure generate command, but still, the generated reports show the default product categories.

Please let me know if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Started working in to this 2 days back. For me below **categories.json** works fine
Please try.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Skipped tests",
    "messageRegex": ".*",
    "matchedStatuses": [ "skipped" ]
  },
    {
      "name": "Element not found",
      "traceRegex": ".*NoSuchElementError.*",
      "matchedStatuses": [ "failed" ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Broken tests",
      "traceRegex": "Error.*",
      "matchedStatuses": [ "failed"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Test defect",
      "messageRegex": ".*Expected is not a String or a RegExp.*",
      "matchedStatuses": ["failed"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Product defect",
      "traceRegex": ".*Failed expectation.*", 
      "matchedStatuses": [ "failed" ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Passed tests",
      "matchedStatuses": ["passed"]
    }
  ]
```

Also please see this 
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/552

Comment: This one is not working as well. Let me give u little insights about my efforts. I am trying to add a new category apart from Test and Product(default category mentioned in allure base code). The new category will show failed test cases in which there is an assertion message in the stack trace. I am generating the report using allure command line 2.6  or Jenkins plugin but still, i can see only 2 default category in the report.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like content of your `categories.json` is not a valid JSON, because of trailing commas placement. Should be:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Iored tests", 
    "matchedStatuses": ["skipped"] 
  },
  {
    "name": "Inructure problems",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken", "failed"],
    "messageRegex": ".*bye-bye.*"
  },
  {
    "name": "Outed tests",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken"],
    "traceRegex": ".*FileNotFoundException.*"
  },
  {
    "name": "Prot defects",
    "matchedStatuses": ["failed"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Tst defects",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken"]
  }
]
```